# Teddy made me do it short story

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, toys

I am looking for the title of a short story where a little boy kills his father because "teddy made me do it". The idea is the teddy bears indoctrinate the kids to behave correctly, but someone hacks the teddy bear for political purposes.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a guess, but how about "[I Always Do What Teddy Says](https://www.sffchronicles.com/threads/550692/)" by Harry Harrison.  Description sorta fits:

> "the name of an old (70's maybe?) sci fi story about a future where
> children are raised by teddy bears - the teddy bears are kind of like
> "skinner boxes" they provide all of the moral and social training that
> children need to become positive, functioning citizens. the
> protagonist in the story has killed a politician but can't reconcile
> his action because it should be impossible- all teddy bears are
> programmed to teach that murder is wrong, ergo murder has ceased to
> exist. the denouement happens when he questions his teddy bear about
> murder and his teddy bear is silent- he realizes that he has been
> groomed from birth to be a political assassin - his teddy bear was
> programmed without this crucial information"

[ISFDB entry here](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?62854).

Comment: I agree. As soon as I saw the question (a minute ago), I instantly thought: "Wasn't that a short story by Harry Harrison?" Couldn't remember the title, but I came in and saw you'd already given the same answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've read it, but don't own a copy, apparently.

Comment: That sounds like it - thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome! If this answer is correct, please mark it by clicking on the gray check mark to the left of the answer. Thanks!